# Better to use SelectedIndex or SelectedItem for ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have a `ComboBox` with the values "One, Two, Three"

As a general rule, when testing for conditional events based on the `ComboBox` selection, would it be better to reference the ComboBox.SelectedItem or ComboBox.SelectedIndex?

```
If (ComboBox.SelectedItem = "One")
```

or

```
If (ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0)
```

Or does neither have an advantage over the other?

Comment: What is more readable in your opinion?

Comment: It only depends on what you and your team decide is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Okay, I was just wondering if processing-wise one works better than the other

Comment: Problem #1 isn't the "==" the equality operator? I think you're doing assignment here.

Comment: not in vb.net 2005, but just treat it as pseudocode if you want

Comment: I just wanted a general opinion from others on whether one has an advantage over the other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find `SelectedIndex` easier to use because you can work on a number and when there is no selection you don't have to handle the null. SelectedItem could be null and you should remember this when trying to access that property.

Usually SelectedItem and SelectedIndex are used inside a SelectedIndexChanged event and it easy to forget the Nothing possibility

```
Dim curValue = Combo.SelectedItem.ToString() ' <- Possible NullReferenceException'
  .....
```

However, if we are just talking about comparison then there is a very small advantage for SelectedIndex because there is no loading and testing of a string.

```
ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
if(b.SelectedItem == "One")
  Console.WriteLine("OK");
if(b.SelectedIndex == 0)
  Console.WriteLine("OK");
```

IL Code

```
IL_0000:  newobj      System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // b
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // b
IL_0007:  callvirt    System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_SelectedItem
IL_000C:  ldstr       "One"
IL_0011:  bne.un.s    IL_001D
IL_0013:  ldstr       "OK"
IL_0018:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_001D:  ldloc.0     // b
IL_001E:  callvirt    System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.get_SelectedIndex
IL_0023:  brtrue.s    IL_002F
IL_0025:  ldstr       "OK"
IL_002A:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

But we are in the realm of micro-optimizations and, as said in a  comment, use what is more readable for you.

Comment: Why do you need to check for `Nothing` at all?

Comment: Usually SelectedItem is used inside a SelectedIndexChanged event and you should remember that it can be null to avoid the NullReferenceExceptio. I agree that in the example above is not really needed

Answer (score 3):

SelectedIndex is guaranteed to be unique, SelectedItem is not